# Unable to acquire value of selected item in dropdown

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling to get the value of the selected item in a dropdown

```js
$('.submitbutton').on('click', function() {
  var valueofitem = $(this).parent().children('.names :selected').attr('value');
  console.log(valueofitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thingselect">

  <select name="names1" class="names">
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Bike</option>
    <option value="3">Train</option>
  </select>

  <div class="submitbutton">
    <button>
        Send                                            
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I select one of the options and click Send, value the is printed to the console is 'undefined' and I can't seem to figure out why.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.children` to `.find`.

When you use `.children()`, it's looking for a child that matches the `.names :selected` selector, but the child is just `.names`, `:selected` matches a granchild.

`.find()` searches further down.

```js
$('.submitbutton').on('click', function() {
  var valueofitem = $(this).parent().find('.names :selected').attr('value');
  console.log(valueofitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thingselect">

  <select name="names1" class="names">
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Bike</option>
    <option value="3">Train</option>
  </select>

  <div class="submitbutton">
    <button>
        Send                                            
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of the selected option by using `.val()` on the select element (so there is no need to target the selected option) like so:

```js
$('.submitbutton').on('click', function() {
  var valueofitem = $(this).parent().children('.names').val();
  console.log(valueofitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thingselect">

  <select name="names1" class="names">
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Bike</option>
    <option value="3">Train</option>
  </select>

  <div class="submitbutton">
    <button>Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or simply get the `.val()` of the `.names` class:

```js
$('.submitbutton').on('click', function() {
  var valueofitem = $('.names').val();
  console.log(valueofitem);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thingselect">

  <select name="names1" class="names">
    <option value="1">Car</option>
    <option value="2">Bike</option>
    <option value="3">Train</option>
  </select>

  <div class="submitbutton">
    <button>Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```